# Perl:Error in increment

Tags: perl

I am trying to increase three numb 3,4,6 from num+0.1 to num+0.7 all numbers are working fine except 3. Why?

```
foreach my $num(3,4,6){

    for(my $state=$num+0.1;$state<=$num+0.7;$state+=0.1){
            print $state."\n";
    }

}
```

Output:
[image]
This continues even if I hardcode and print only till 3.6.

```
for(my $state=3;$state<=3.7;$state+=0.1){
        print $state."\n";
}
```

Comment: Please search `[c] float compare` in SO, there are too many questions about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math::BigFloat;`

like this:

```
#!C:/path/of/perl.exe -w

use Math::BigFloat ':constant';

use warnings;
use strict;

foreach my $num(3,4,6) {

    for(my $state=$num+0.1;$state<=$num+0.7;$state+=0.1){
            print $state."\n";
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5
3.6
3.7
4.1
4.2
4.3
4.4
4.5
4.6
4.7
6.1
6.2
6.3
6.4
6.5
6.6
6.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $num ( 3, 4, 6 ) {
    for my $i ( 1 .. 7 ) {
        print $num + $i / 10, "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5
3.6
3.7
4.1
4.2
4.3
4.4
4.5
4.6
4.7
6.1
6.2
6.3
6.4
6.5
6.6
6.7
```